# Formula to increase and decrease amount by a percentage found in other cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to create a formula that will reduce and increase a cell value by percentages found in other cells and finding it difficult so hoping someone can help with what i'm trying to do.

I've attached a sample sheet below with comments with what i am trying to achieve, probably super easy but my brain is fried!

if you need any other info please let me know and I'll do my best to provide.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b-nhNYoamsMr2vFW1YZQvLXLuSksH83iW1weHtDDe3Q/edit#gid=2100307022

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this formula for the 5 weeks in just the first cell:

```
=MAP(B7:B11,BYROW(E7:H11,LAMBDA(e,SUMPRODUCT(e,TRANSPOSE(G31:G34)))),LAMBDA(bonus,perc,bonus*(IF(perc>0,1,SI(perc<-1,0,1+perc)))))
```

Added in sheet Solution 1

Comment: Nice Martín +10

Comment: This was the simplest option to implement and does what i need so i'll mark this as the answer. Thank you though to all that replied.

Answer (score 0):

[New Sheet here labeled "Blind"](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b-nhNYoamsMr2vFW1YZQvLXLuSksH83iW1weHtDDe3Q/edit#gid=581645536)

- Adjusted Bonus **=>** 0
- Adjusted Bonus **=<** Gross Bonus

## Formulas

---

###### Main Formula: `$C$5`

```
=BYROW(_audit, 
    LAMBDA(x, 
       OFFSET(INDEX(x,1,1),0,-4)*
       MIN(MAX(1+SUMPRODUCT(
          {rRed, rAmb, rGreen, rGold}*x),0),1)))
```

---

###### Adjusted +/- % Formula: `$K$5`

<sup>**Note:**   *Not needed by **Main Formula `$C$5`** but provides feedback on the calculations being done*</sup>

```
=BYROW(_audit, 
    LAMBDA(x,
      {MIN(MAX(SUMPRODUCT({_re, _am, _gr, _go}*x),-1),0),
      SUMPRODUCT({_re, _am, _gr, _go}*x)}))
```

---

##### Total Gross +/- % Formula: `$L$10`

<sup>**Note:**   *Again, not needed by the **Main Formula `$C$5`** but provides feedback on calculations*</sup>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(_bonusG*(grossPlusMinus))/SUM(_bonusG)
```

## Sample Tables

---

###### Main Table

<sup>**Note:**   *Empty `columns A, D, J` and `rows 1-3` were omitted to save space*</sup>

|  | B | C | E | F | G | H | I | K | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **4** | **Gross** **Bonus** | **Adj'd.** **Bonus** |  | **Re** | **Am** | **Gr** | **Go** | **Adj'd.** **+/- %** | **Gross** **+/- %** |
| **5** | £200 | **£100** | Wk 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |  | **- 50 %** | - 50 % |
| **6** | £200 | **£200** | Wk 2 |  |  | 2 |  | ⁠⁠ **-** | + 50 % |
| **7** | £200 | **£0** | Wk 3 | 4 |  |  |  | **- 100 %** | - 200 % |
| **8** | £200 | **£150** | Wk 4 | 2 | 2 | 1 |  | **- 25 %** | - 25 % |
| **9** | £0 | **£0** | Wk 5 |  |  |  |  | ⁠ **-** | ⁠⁠ - |
| **10** | **£800** | **£450** | **⇐ Totals ⇒** | **8** | **3** | **4** |  | **- 44 %** | **- 56 %** |

###### Rate Table

| Category | Change | Named Range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | - 50 % | _re |
| Amber | + 25 % | _am |
| Green | + 25 % | _gr |
| Gold | ⁠– | _go |

###### Named Ranges

| Name | Range | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| _audit | F5:I9 | Audit Results Table |
| _bonusG | B5:B9 | Gross Bonus Column |
| _bonusA | C5:C9 | Adjusted Bonus Column |
| _re | C15 | Red +/- % |
| _am | C16 | Amber +/- % |
| _gr | C17 | Green +/- % |
| _go | C18 | Gold +/- % |
| _gPlusMinus | L5:L9 | Gross +/- % Bonus Column |

### Images

---

**Main Formula: `$C$5`**
[image]

**Adjusted +/- % Formula: `$K$5`**
[image]

**Total Gross +/- % Formula: `$L$10`**
[image]